# Improving my Python code

Tags: python, numpy

I want to re-write these line of code to be more Pythonian, but I fail to find a good way:

```
conversion_factor = 1.0 # for easier reading
mass_left = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]
mass_right = [0.3, 0.5, 0.1]
volumes = np.array([0.4, 0.7, 0.2])**3

# Unhappy with next two lines
left_rho = np.array([[(i*conversion_factor)/j for i in mass_left] for j in volumes])
right_rho = np.array([[(i*conversion_factor)/j for i in mass_right] for j in volumes])
```

My idea was to go for something more like:

```
masses = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.3, 0.5, 0.1]]
rhos = []

# This line
rhos.append(np.array([[(i*conversion_factor)/j for i in mass_left] for j in volumes]))
```

In the above line, I'm missing a proper way to address the two nested lists in my masses list. What would be the most Pythonian way to proceed here? Or would you suggest to make a function from my calculation and use map() or itertools? If possible, I don't want to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `conversion_factor` is scalar:

```
mass_left = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.7])
mass_right = array([0.3, 0.5, 0.1])
volumes = array([0.4, 0.7, 0.2])**3

left_rho = mass_left[None, :] * conversion_factor / volumes[:, None]
```

That version uses [NewAxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give us the conversion factor - for the moment I will take it as 1?

You did okay with updating mass_left and mass_right to mass. Does that work for you?

```
 volumes = []
 for i in [0.4, 0.7, 0.2]: # your original code - assuming you need them?
     volumes.append(i**3);

 rhos = [];
 temp = [];
 elems = 0;
 for i in mass:
     for j in volumes:
         temp.append(conv_factor*i[elems]/j)
         elems += 1;
     elems = 0;
     rho.append(temp);
     temp = [];




 # The result comes as
 # [[1.5624999999999998, 0.5830903790087465, 87.49999999999997], [4.687499999999999, 
 # 1.4577259475218662, 12.499999999999998]]
 #
 #
```

Is that the result you expect?

N.B. I didn't use any numpy if you haven't noticed. This removes any dependency on the non-standard Python modules which you will use otherwise as add-ons.

Comment: But this would produce a list [a,b,c,d,e,f] - I want [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]].

Comment: @xtlc           I have updated my answer - please see and comment if the results don't match what you expected :)